# How to add plot legends when combining `Plot` with `DiscretePlot`?

Tags: visualization

I often end up with discrete data + continuous approximation, and need to plot them in the same chart, with plot legends. What is a good pattern for doing this?

Adding `PlotLegends` to Show doesn't work, I'm guessing it's not a property of Show.

Here's an example:

```
integral[s_] := (
  n - s - ((-1 + s) s HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 2 - s}, {2, 3}, 1/n])/(
   2 n) + s (EulerGamma - Log[n] + PolyGamma[0, s]))/n;
sum[s_] := Sum[1/n (1 - 1/i)^s, {i, 1, n}];
Block[{n = 1000},
 plot1 = Plot[integral[s], {s, 1, 50}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
 plot2 = DiscretePlot[sum[s], {s, 1, 50}, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5]];
 Show[plot1, plot2, PlotLegends -> {"approximation", "exact"}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Try [Legended](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

Comment: You can just add `PlotLegends` to the individual plots, and `Show` should combine them properly